# How to extract xml data from a CrossRef using R?

Tags: xml, r, metadata

If you put in your CrossRef email the following URL produces an XML file

```
"http://www.crossref.org/openurl?title=Science&aulast=Fernández&date=2009&multihit=true&pid=your.crossref.email"
```

An example file is available here:

[crossref.xml](https://raw.github.com/edielivon/stack_examples/master/crossref.xml)

I wish to extract the list of DOI (Digital Object Identifies) into an data.frame in R.
I wish to do so using one of the general R xml packages

```
library(XML) or library(tm)
```

I have tried

```
doc<-xmlTreeParse(file)
top<-xmlRoot(doc)
```

but can not figure out how to go from here

```
top[[1]]["doi"]
```

does not work.

Comment: Thanks to @G. Grothendieck, a working function is now available at [crossref_get_doi](https://github.com/edielivon/Useful-R-functions/tree/master/Meta_analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlTreeParse("crossref.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
root <- xmlRoot(doc)
xpathSApply(root, "//x:doi", xmlValue, namespaces = "x")
```

Comment: It seems so simple presented like this!

Answer (score 2):

I and others as part of [rOpenSci](https://github.com/ropensci) have some functions for hitting the Crossref API, functions crossref and crossref_r [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rplos/tree/master/R).

Comment: Crossref functions are now in a separate R package `rcrossref` https://github.com/ropensci/rcrossref/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same lack of understanding. I spent a day and half looking and finaly came across this post.

Thanks!!!