# Read MS word headers into R

Tags: r, ms-word

I am trying to read a bunch of MS Word files (.doc and .docx) into R.
I have to read in the header along with the contents.

I'm able to do this for .docx files by using the method given by @BondedDust in [how do I create a corpus of *.docx files with tm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065952/how-do-i-create-a-corpus-of-docx-files-with-tm)
The header gets saved in a separate XML which I can read.

However, I am unable to do this for .doc files. I tried saving the file as html, txt etc., all of which do not capture the header.
I also tried to use readDOC() from the tm package, but there is very little documentation on using it.

Can anyone please help?

I am running R 3.0.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

To use `readDOC()` you'll need [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/#Windows) installed.

The `readDOC()` function requires a `list` as the first parameter and also the language specified (the ID is optional). Here's a sample run with a hastily crafted `.doc` file:

```
wordReader <- readDOC()
word_info <- wordReader(list(uri="test1.doc"), language="en")

word_info$meta

## Metadata:
##   author       : character(0)
##   datetimestamp: 2014-10-01 11:07:52
##   description  : character(0)
##   heading      : character(0)
##   id           : test1.doc
##   language     : en
##   origin       : character(0)

word_info$content

## [1] ""     "Test" ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But still I'm unable to read the header - [MS word header](https://github.com/tm2222/testRepo/blob/master/MS%20word%20header.png).  
I have given a GitHub link to see the screenshot of the MS word header section since I don't have enough reputation to add an image.

Comment: I am now looking at ways to bulk convert doc to docx. I will then read docx into R.