# Using docx2txt in R

Tags: r, pdf, docx, tm, corpus

I have used the following code within R to convert a PDF file to a text file for future use of the tm package.  I am using the downloaded "pdftotext.exe" file.

This code is working properly and produces a "txt" for every PDF in the directory.

```
myfiles <- list.files(path = dir04, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)
lapply(myfiles, function(i) system(paste('"C:/xpdf/xpdfbin-win-3.04/bin64/pdftotext.exe"',paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE))
```

I am trying to figure out how to use "docx2txt" in a similar manner.  However, the file formats are not .exe files.  Can I use the "docx2txt-1.4" or "docx2txt-1.4.tar" in the same manner?  The following code provides an error for each file.

```
myfiles <- list.files(path = dir08, pattern = "docx",  full.names = TRUE)
lapply(myfiles, function(i) system(paste('"C:/docx2txt/docx2txt-1.4.gz"',paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE))
```

Warning
running command '"C:/docx2txt/docx2txt-1.4.gz" "C:/....docx"' had status 127

[how do I create a corpus of *.docx files with tm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065952/how-do-i-create-a-corpus-of-docx-files-with-tm) doesn't have quite enough info.

Comment: You can't execute a gz file - it's an archive. You need to extract it, and somewhere inside will be the exe you need.

Comment: Sorry, I extracted the gz file, but I'm left with a ".4" file or a ".tar" file and those aren't working either.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries - [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) is an archive too - you need to extract it as well!

Comment: To scale it back while attempting to run docx2txt.pl I ran the following code.  I first defined infile.docx then                                                                                                            `cmd <- paste("perl","C:/docx2txt/docx2txt-1.4/docx2txt-1.4/docx2txt-1.4/docx2txt.pl",infile.docx)
system(cmd)`
I received the following message: Failed to locate unzip command '/usr/bin/unzip'!

Comment: Well, a docx is actually a zip file, so it's not surprising that it expects zip, but that looks like a Unix path, so you may have trouble getting it to work. You may need to contact the docx2txt people...

Comment: You need to look at `config_unzip_opts`, which allows you to change the unzip program used. See here for details: http://sourceforge.net/projects/docx2txt/files/docx2txt/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a ".docx" file to ".txt" with the following code which is a different approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Word <- "C:\\temp.docx"
path_TXT <- "C:\\temp.txt"
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_Word),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs(path_TXT, FileFormat = 4) # Converts word document to txt
text <- readLines(path_TXT)
text
```