# Python - download file using GET form

Tags: python

I am trying to write a  script that downloads a xlsx file and saves it to the computer. This file doesn't have a specific path and it gets generated after filling a `GET` form. There are two submit buttons.

The first one makes a list of results under the form (I can do it).
The second one creates a xlsx file and asks where to save it.

```
<form action="/search" method="get" id="frm-detailedSearchForm">
...

<input type="text" name="publication_date[from]" class="date" tabindex="1" id="frm-detailedSearchForm-publication_date-from" data-nette-rules='[{"op":":filled","rules":[{"op":":pattern","msg":"Nevalidní formát data (dd.mm.rrrr)","arg":"\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}.\\d{4}"}],"control":"publication_date[from]"}]'>

...
<input type="submit" name="search" class="w-button btn ajax" tabindex="27" value="Search">
<input type="submit" name="export" class="w-button btn" tabindex="28" value="Export">
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="detailedSearchForm-submit"></form>
```

Comment: You should always show us the python code you have developed so far. Have a look here to get started  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1171409/640916

Comment: I tryied many type of codes so it is hard to say which one is the best to start.

    browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.open(url)
    browser.select_form(nr=1)

    browser.form["publication_date[from]"] = "01.09.2016"
    browser.form["publication_date[to]"] = "01.09.2016"

This works for me, when I use browser.submit(). When I tryied to use browser.submit(nr=1) nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

if I get you right you're trying to write a script that interacts with an existing website, fills a form, downloads a file and saves it, right?
you're not the one writing the website.

is so - I highly recommend using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to automate the task of filling the form **on top of a real browser**. it's a bit hard to start but much much more resilient.

while you theoretically could write a script that downloads the file from a url that fakes a form submission, this attitude is often times a source of troubles. if the site is over some level of complexity - the likelihood of this attitude to work is very low.

Comment: Exactly, I am not the one writing the website. I just need something that everyday download files pubslihed the day before (fill the publication_date[from] and dowload and save file to my computer).

Comment: @MartinaKarbusická - if you find my answer useful - please feel free to accept it/upvote