# How can I link to a specific search result

Tags: web-scraping, hyperlink

I need to scrape specific search results from this website: https://forms.justice.govt.nz/search/TT/

However, after searching for the results, the URL does not change.

Is there some sort of hidden URL that I can find and link to?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome

@mixonic posted a great answer to this over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170120/web-scraping-to-fill-out-and-retrieve-search-forms).

What you need to do is automate some of the actions on your page. You can do this by finding their id or classname, setting a value and triggering the click to submit.

After that you can scrape the result as needed.